# Array modifier offset problem

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

I'm having a problem with the relative offset the array modifier creates for the added objects.

When I add the modifier, the relative offset is set to 1.0 in one direction and 0.0 in the other two. To me, this means that the object is being duplicated in only one direction. However, the new object appears to the upper right of the original, as if it had been moved by equal amounts in x- and y-direction. There is no displacement in z-direction.

When I enter a value into the upper box of the relative offset (x I assume?) and enter the same but negative value in the second box (y?), the object appears moved in x-direction only.

In another blender file I received from a friend the Array modifier on a very similar object behaves normally, moving the copies in only one direction. 
Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: After some more investigation, I think this is because the bounding box of the object is not parallel to the world axes, so the local axes which it is moved along are off. Can someone confirm that? The object was created by joining several smaller ones but from the moment of joining onwards the bounding box is at about a 45 degree angle.

Comment: The Array modifier offset can differ if object has rotation unapplied, i.e. it was rotated in Object mode (Ctrl+A > Rotation to apply).